# how to create Event which repeats every specific day

Tags: ios, events, icalendar

I do have a function like , On every thursday there is a show coming in my application and I want to provide add event functionality which will set event for every thursday for example next 5 years.

I know how to add Event but do not have idea how to add event for every thursday or a specific day.

Thanks your for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of examples at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3
If unsure, you can always create such an event in your calendar client of choice and then export this event. Or you can go to http://jkbr.github.io/rrule/ and build it. For example http://jkbr.github.io/rrule/#/text/every%20week%20on%20Thursday%20until%20April%2017,%202019